# Understanding Prepared Statements; mysqli_real_escape_string and htmlspecialchars

Tags: php

I'm a newbie to programming and know only procedural PHP. I've been studying prepared statements and other safety issues. I have a few questions about my code below:

I have a table of Footwear sizes that have an identical size and sizeid (e.g. SIZE: 9.5 = sizeID: also 9.5).

My processing file checking then retrieving selected size from a previous html form page.

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("servert", "user", "passW", "footwear");
        if(!$link){
            printf("Can't connect to the locatlhost. Errorcode: %d\n", mysqli_connect_errno());
        }
if (!mysqli_select_db($link, "footwear")) {
   printf("Can't connect to Database. Errorcode: %d\n", mysqli_connect_errno());
}      
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($link);
if($stmt=mysqli_prepare($link,"SELECT `sizeid`,`size` FROM `size` WHERE `sizeid`"))
{
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"i", $sizeid);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,$sizeid, $size);
mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
        if(!floatval($size)) {
        echo "Invalid size. Pick another one.";
        }
        else {          
        $size = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $size);
        $sizeid= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $sizeid);

        $size= htmlspecialchars($size, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        $sizeid= htmlspecialchars($sizeid, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); 

        $size = sprintf('%01.1f', $size);
        $sizeid = sprintf('%01.1f', $sizeid);

echo " Size: $size";
}
}
?>
```

The code works but I want to better understand  how it does.

1. Is this line (I followed PHP.NET) necessary/critical?:

```
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($link);
```

Apparently the code works just fine when I omit it and go directly to the query:

```
$stmt=mysqli_prepare($link,"SELECT `sizeid`,`size` FROM `size` WHERE `sizeid`");
```

2. From what I've read, my understanding is that question marks (?) are used as place holders which are then bound in mysqli_stmt_bind_param ; but when I try

```
if($stmt=mysqli_prepare($link,"SELECT `sizeid`,`size` FROM `size` WHERE `?`"))…
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"i", $sizeid);
```

it does not work. 
Isn't the idea to "hide" the variable?

3. Is it ok or does it hurt to have `mysqli_real_escape_string` and `htmlspecialchars` together. If not why and if it's alright, should one be called out before the other, if that makes any difference?

4. I need the size to output as a float since real world shoe sizes are so( i.e. 7.5, 9.5, etc.)
Is there any danger in the method I've chosen to do so (floatval and sprint)?

Comment: The `?` placeholders are only for the values: ``WHERE `size` = ?``

Comment: Regarding #3, `mysqli_real_escape_string` and `htmlspecialchars` do **very different things.** I suggest you read the documentation for each.

Comment: Thanks, Rocket Hazmat. This part: WHERE `size` = ?, I know and understand. So, I take it that the way I wrote it is correct and safe?

Comment: Thanks,  Matt Ball. I do undestand that the two functions do different things. Just wanted expert word whether there is any danger or conflict between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysqli_stmt_init` creates a prepared statement object.  `mysqli_prepare` assigns a query to it.  You're supposed to pass `$stmt` to `mysqli_prepare`  `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` is used to pass the values to replace the `?` with

```
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($link);
// $prepared will be a boolean
// the `?` are just for the values you want to pass
$prepared = mysqli_prepare($stmt, "SELECT `sizeid`,`size` FROM `size` WHERE `sizeid` = ?");

if($prepared){
    // Replace the `?` with a value in the WHERE clause
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $sizeid);

    // run the query
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    // assign result variables
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $result_sizeid, $result_size);

    // get results
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

    echo htmlspecialchars("The sizeid is $result_sizeid and the size is $result_size");

    // close prepared statement
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
else{
    die(mysqli_errno($link));
}

mysqli_close($link);
```

PHP Docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php

`mysqli_real_escape_string` is *only* used to escape values before inserting them into the database.  Your prepared statements do this for you, so `mysqli_real_escape_string` is *not needed* here at all.

`htmlspecialchars` is used to display HTML characters on a webpage, it escapes them so they don't get parsed by the browser.